# Java - Mismatch and method is undefined error

Tags: error-handling, mismatch, java

//  The section below is what raises the error, I am modifying a simple banking application i found online. I am very new to Java, about 3 days I've been dabbling in it, and thought this would be a good little activity to do to get me used to the syntax of the code and methods etc. I have been looking at this problem for about a day now and cant figure out what exactly the problem is. The only thing that would come to mind would be that the showMenu() method is possibly out of scope for the main section im referring it in, however im not to sure.

P.S. If i have missed anything out that could be of us, i apologise as i have never posted on here before!

EDIT - The new error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The constructor BankApplication.BankAccount(String, String) is undefined
    The method showMenu() is undefined for the type BankApplication.BankAccount

    at BankApplication.main(bank.java:9)




public static void main(String[] args)
{
 BankAccount obj1 = new BankAccount("Ye Ma", "X Æ A-12");
 obj1.showMenu();
}
```

//The showMenu code

```
void showMenu()
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Welcome to the Bank");
    System.out.println("Your Customer ID is: " + cID);
    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("1. To view you Bank Balance.");
    System.out.println("2. To make a deposit.");
    System.out.println("3. To make a withdrawel.");
    System.out.println("4. To view your previous transaction.");
    System.out.println("5. To exit.");
    
    do
    {
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("        Choose an option        ");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("");
        option = sc.nextInt();

        if(option == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("  Your bank balance is: " + balance);
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------");

            break;
        }
        else if(option == 2)
        {
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("How much would you like to deposit?");
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------");
            int amount = sc.nextInt();
            deposit(amount);
            break;
        } 
        else if(option == 3)
        {
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("  How much would you like to withdraw?: ");
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------");
            int amount = sc.nextInt();
            withdraw(amount);
            break;
        }
        else if(option == 4)
        {
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Your previous transaction was: " + getPreviousTransaction(amount));
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("");
        }
        else if(option == 5)
        {
            System.out.println("**********************************");
            System.out.println("        END OF APPLICATION        ");
            System.out.println("**********************************");
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid option, please choose a valid option.");
        }
    }while(option != 5);
```

Comment: What is the actual error, in what line?

Comment: Ah sorry thought i included it, i will edit the question and include it.

Comment: The following details could help. How are the classes `BankApplication` and `BankAccount` organised? Did you import `BankAccount` in `BankApplication.java`? Where is `showMenu` defined? Where is `BankAccount` defined?

Answer (score 0):

i think you are trying to call showMenu() which is not available in BankAccount class.